# PhpStorm what does this file tree icon (sheet with X) mean?

Tags: phpstorm

A file suddenly has this icon and I can't see how it got it. I have searched [context menu and legends](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/class-diagram-toolbar-context-menu-and-legend.html) and [symbol reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/symbols-reference.html#d342455e7) on the JetBrains repository but can't see the icon.

Also looked at [file types icons](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/file-types-recognized-by-webstorm.html). and the symbol is similar to "text file" but has the additional "X" in the corner, which to me implies deletion but the file exists.

[image]

Stupid question but... I can't see what it is. The file still exists and the file is auto generated. What does this icon mean?

Comment: Maybe the file is excluded from inspection

Comment: @DanielGale that may be the sort of thing, it's excluded from something (judging from the icon X) but can that be done from the file tree window.. I thought I'd have to meddle around in the settings to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Found it.**

I had in-advertently marked the file as "mark as Plain Text" in the context menu.

[image]

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2011/04/exclude-single-file/
The reason you would want it marked as plain text is that you have a New.css and a New.min.css. You do not want code completion for both since one will be a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @DanielGale thanks for the comments, I don't deliberatly mark any files as plain text; for code completion I wold maybe mark it's parent file but the site would always reference the `min.css` file rather than it's parents. The icon does appear in your blog post but doesn't appear on JetBrains icons list. Cheers.